# speed helper for difflib

Tags: python, difflib

I'm using difflib (`SequenceMatcher`) for this task: for 3000 book titles with typo's, find the closest match in a database with 128500 titles that (allegedly) are fault-free. The code is easy enough:

```
# imp and dbf are lists of ordered dicts 
# imp contains the messy titles to match (in imp['Titel:'] in each dict)
# dbf contains the clean titles to match against (in dbf['ti']) 

threshold = 0.65

for imprec in imp:
    bestmatch = threshold
    mpair = []

    try: 
        i = imprec['Titel:'][0]
    except KeyError: 
        print('record with InvNo %s has no title' % imprec['InvNo:'])
        continue

    for rec in dbf: 
        try: 
            r = rec['ti'][0]
        except KeyError:
            # record has no title. Do not make screen output.. 
            # print('record with priref %s has no title' % rec['%0'])
            continue

        m = SequenceMatcher(None, i, r)
        if m.ratio() > bestmatch: 
            bestmatch = m.ratio()
            mpair = [bestmatch, imprec, rec]
            print('{} matches for {:4.1f}% with {}'.format(i, m.ratio()*100, r))

    if bestmatch > threshold:
        match.append(mpair)
    else:
        nonmatch.append(imprec)
```

It works, but it's slow. After about 100 hours, it's at about 40% in the list of 3000. The problem is, of course: 3000 iterations of 128500 titles = 385.5 million calls to `SequenceMatcher`.

I'm looking for ways to optimise this. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834570/how-to-do-fuzzy-string-search-without-a-heavy-database), the OP made an index, queried that, and SequenceMatched the yield of that query. I think that is a good approach, but how to implement it?

The script is just a once-off, no fancy app or anything. My hour budget is limited.

**edit** Whoosh supports [fuzzy term queries](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/parsing.html#adding-fuzzy-term-queries). SQLite has `LIKE`.

Are there other possibilities I should look into?

Comment: I don't know enough to give you a proper answer, but look into employing generators to try and save some resources.  Also consider dividing your list of 3000 titles up into blocks and check them simultaneously with threading.  At some point though you may need to accept that processing lots of data just takes a lot of time

Comment: Thanks! Splitting the task up across more processors is a good idea, and easy to do. It's now at 70%, so if I have to run it again.. :-)